# System.Drawing objects unmanaged resource disposing

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dispose, unmanaged, system.drawing

I have the following code:

```
using System.Drawing;
...
Graphics _graphics = Graphics.FromImage(...)
...
public void Draw(Stream stream, Rectangle rect, Color color) {
    _graphics.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color), 0, 0, Width, Height);
    _graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap(stream), rect);
}
```

Should I surround the drawImage with using on `new Bitmap(...)`? 
Same question on the `new SolidBrush(...)`

Comment: Yes, I think you should. I would also do that for unmanaged resources. It might allow the GC to dispose of them earlier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you should wrap them in using statements. Also you should ensure that the Dispose methods is invoked on the `_graphics` instance that you are using in this class. This could be done by having the containing class implement `IDisposable` so that the consumer of this class could wrap it in a `using` statement.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, disposing these resources is important.  Particularly a bitmap is troublesome, it consumes lots of unmanaged memory to store the pixel data but the managed Bitmap class wrapper is very small.  You can create a *lot* of Bitmap objects before triggering a garbage collection, giving high odds that the Bitmap constructor will start failing because there is no more unmanaged memory left.

So rewrite it like this:

```
public void Draw(Stream stream, Rectangle rect, Color color) {
    using (var bmp = new Bitmap(stream))
    using (var brush = new SolidBrush(Color)) {
        _graphics.FillRectangle(brush, 0, 0, Width, Height);
        _graphics.DrawImage(bmp, rect);
    }
}
```