# C#: An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use a PictureBox to create an animation in a Windows Forms app (C#) by drawing on the Bitmap using Graphics. Unfortunately, it looks like I am leaking memory somewhere or allocating too much based on this error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in System.Drawing.dll
Additional information: Out of memory.
```

This is the source code. Desired behavior is a popup with a glitchy animation.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace AnimationApp
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    Form1 form1;
    //Bitmap bmp;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form1 = this;
        form1.TransparencyKey = Color.White;
        FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;

        pictureBox1.Left = 0;
        pictureBox1.Top = 0;
        pictureBox1.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        pictureBox1.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Interval = 10;
        timer.Tick += timer_tick;

    }
    Random rand = new Random();
    int partsection = 0;
    int waitint = 0;
    int ran1 = 0;
    int ran2 = 0;
    int intensifies = 0;
    public void timer_tick(object e, EventArgs ea)
    {
        Bitmap bmp;
        bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);

        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp))
        {
            if (partsection == -1)
            {

            }
           
            else if (partsection<300)
            {
                if (waitint == 0)
                {

                    ran1 = rand.Next(0, pictureBox1.Width);
                            ran2 = rand.Next(0, pictureBox1.Width);
                    waitint = 10;
                }
                else
                {
                    waitint--;
                }

                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Green), (float)ran1, (float)0, 3, pictureBox1.Height);
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.DarkGreen), (float)ran2, (float)0, 3, pictureBox1.Height);

                partsection++;
            }
            else if (partsection < 1000)
            {
                if (intensifies < 255)
                {
                    intensifies++;

                }
                else
                {

                }
                g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(intensifies,Color.Black)), (float)0, (float)0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
            }

        }
        pictureBox1.Image = bmp;
     
    }
}
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You're leaking `SolidBrush`es, that's for sure. You need to dispose of them. The thing I'm not sure about is if you'd also need to dispose explicitly of the old `pictureBox1.Image` image. 100 ticks per seconds is also pretty excessive...

Comment: What code do I need to change? Sorry, I have only been coding in c# for about half a year.

Comment: Your `SolidBrush` should be either in `using` statements like your `Graphics` or be declared on a separate line so you can call `Dispose` on em. Or even better, declare them at class level and reuse the same brushes instead of creating a new one each time. For the `pictureBox`, you can look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2809026/2316200). And you can change your `Tick` to 33 for about 30FPS, which should be fluid enough and less taxing on the hardware. Not sure about the picturebox though.

Comment: Ok, so like 
    SolidBrush sb1 = new SolidBrush(); 
    //Use Code
    sb1.Dispose();

Comment: Ok, I tried this on all the solid brush code, the error takes a little longer to activate but still activates.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you can't draw directly on the form? And how big is your screen? Tried it on my 1440x900 and it doesn't throw `OutOfMemoryException` exception. And I'm not sure if GDI leak is the problem here also, Task Manager showed only ~40 GDI object... max.

Comment: Change the code to use fixed screen resolution of 3840x2160, and it does throw `OutOfMemoryException ` for me. So apparently it does leak, albeit due to late triggered GC (see Ian answer below). Adding `if (pictureBox1.Image != null) pictureBox1.Image.Dispose();` right before `pictureBox1.Image = bmp;` would probably solve the out of memory issue...

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault I was wondering about the same thing earlier this week. Apparently the answer is _yes_, the `PictureBox` setter does not dispose the image on its own: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2613286/if-i-replace-an-image-in-a-picturebox-control-should-i-dispose-the-original-ima

Comment: Thank you @IronGeek, that solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because some of the resources you use are unmanaged and you do not put it under `using` block or any alternative way to dispose your unmanaged resource after use. The memory is leaked due to that.

For instance, these lines,

```
g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Green), (float)ran1, (float)0, 3, pictureBox1.Height);
g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.DarkGreen), (float)ran2, (float)0, 3, pictureBox1.Height);
```

Can be changed to

```
using (SolidBrush greenBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.Green))
using (SolidBrush darkGreenBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.DarkGreen)) {
    g.FillRectangle(greenBrush , (float)ran1, (float)0, 3, pictureBox1.Height);
    g.FillRectangle(darkGreenBrush, (float)ran2, (float)0, 3, pictureBox1.Height);
}
```

And similarly, this line

```
g.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(intensifies,Color.Black)), (float)0, (float)0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
```

To this

```
using (SolidBrush blackBrush = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(intensifies, Color.Black)))
    g.FillRectangle(blackBrush, (float)0, (float)0, pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
```

Another advise is you should check the unmanaged resources on `System.Drawing`. Since there might be more of the unmanaged resources which you show but are not pointed out - or - you do not put in your question but are actually in the other parts of your codes.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433197/what-exactly-are-unmanaged-resources) is more of unmanaged resources:

Here is another explanation for the possibility of `Bitmap` causes the leak (due to small-sized managed `Bitmap` class wrapper, out of memory can be caused because the Garbage Collector is late-triggered), see [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14029451/system-drawing-objects-unmanaged-resource-disposing) by Mr. Hans Passant

Answer (score 1):

Your bitmap needs to be declared as an instance variable of the form.

EDIT

Specifically, uncomment your declaration of the `Bitmap` in the class instance variables.  Next, add the following code:

```
    protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Left = 0;
        pictureBox1.Top = 0;
        pictureBox1.Width = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width;
        pictureBox1.Height = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height;
        bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Width, pictureBox1.Height);
        base.OnResize(e);
    }
```

Why?  Because you need to resize your picture box when the form resizes, or the user changes the screen resolution.  Now, the `Bitmap` is only declared a single time.  I ran the code for several minutes with no ill effects.

BTW, the `pictureBox1` resizing code was removed from the constructor.